# Extract as comma separated value in query SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a result set from a query as shown below.

```
ticketno value
12134   4565
12134   4566
12178   3030
12178   3930
12188   4040
12144   5050
```

I would like to achieve something like below. I am using standard sql only.

```
ticketno value
    12134   4565,4566
    12178   3030,3930
    12188   4040
    12144   5050
```

Query is something like below.

```
select ticketno,GROUP_CONCAT(values) FROM (
                select *  from results) A
```

. Please help in forming the query correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`string_agg()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#string_agg):

```
select ticketno, string_agg(value, ',' order by calue)
from t
group by ticketno;
```